# Fixed gear conversion - hub spacers

Tags: hub, fixed-gear, single-speed

I am converting my 80s steel peugeot to a fixed gear. I have purchased most of the parts an had a wheel built onto a SS hub.

Now, SS hubs are narrower than road hubs - 120mm vs 130mm (although I think my bike is 126mm as it was a 6-speed). The axle on my new hub is plenty long enough to span the rear fork but the hub itself is too narrow.

I've been to a local chain bike shop to see if they stock dedicated spacers but they can't help. I essentially need 2 3mm spacers to bridge fill the extra width.

What's the best way to sort this? I can try a LBS but would a 3mm nut that screws onto the axle suffice? If I can find such a thing...

Comment: You're in the UK? Check out [Velosolo](http://www.velosolo.co.uk). The guy who runs it may be able to help, he's a nice chap and knows an awful lot about going single speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just spring in the dropouts. Its only 3mm on each side, a steel frame will easily bend that much. Just put the wheel in place, then tighten up the nuts on each side.

Comment: Yeah seems like that's the best way. I managed to track down some spacers but when I put them on there was not enough axle thread left for the nuts to get a decent grip on. Ditched the extra spacers and just tightend the nuts to bring the rear fork together (although I think it was actually at 130 so each rear dropout needed to come in 5mm). Seems to fit fine and it doesn't seem the stays are under a lot of stress.

Comment: Now all I need is a crank puller to get the old cranks off and I'm good to finish the build